# Laravel migrate - multiple migrations (files) in one go

Tags: php, laravel, migration

Say, I have multiple migration files updating single table.

e.g.

```
2016_03_20_072730_create_tasks_table.php
2016_03_20_075467_create_tasks_table.php
```

... which came from repo by different team members.
Each is adjusting something in table, e.g. adding a column.

When I try to:

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class CreateTasksTable, because the name is
eady in use in U:\www\b10\database\migrations\2016_03_20_072737_create_tasks_
le.php on line 30


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Cannot declare class CreateTasksTable, because the name is already in use
```

How should one deal with situation as described above?

EDIT

Here is the code:

2016_03_20_072730_create_tasks_table.php:

```
class CreateTasksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
       Schema::table('tasks', function ($table)
       {
           $table->string('task1');
       });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tasks');
    }
}
```

2016_03_20_075467_create_tasks_table.php:

```
class CreateTasksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::table('tasks', function ($table)
        {
            $table->string('task2');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tasks');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each migration has to have a unique class name. Rename the second one to something more sensible, such as `2016_03_20_075467_add_task2_to_tasks_table` and `AddTask2ToTasksTable`, then run `composer dump-autoload` to make Laravel find the changes. Now you can migrate.

Edit: Now that both migrations' code has been edited into the question, I can see that the first migration has the same problem, and should be renamed in the same manner. There's probably an initial create migration sometime further back. You should stop naming editation migrations anything with `create`, since you aren't actually creating the table.

Comment: Yes, I came to same conclusion from error, but migrate was supposed to be so much greater than doing DB by hand. Supposedly you should just get latest repo, run migrate and have a beer. But with this, it seems that by-hand updates are not that far behind this "super-best thing since sliced bread" ;) Now, you have to either adjust migrate file, combine migrate files, or move each to temp and use --path, etc. So, I guess it is a lemon. Lotsa talk, little handle. Unless there is an easy way - hence my question.

Comment: It IS easy - you just have to name your migrations logically. You don't have to do anything in the database. Let's put it this way: it's really easy to work with models as well. But if you try to name two models the same thing, it won't work. Would you argue that makes models hard to work with as well? :) Just teach your team members to give different names to different migrations and that's literally everything you need.

Comment: Migration files is auto-created by Laravel. Since there is a creation shortcut, would it be so hard for Laravel to add some random string/hash to class name? Unless there is something that screams against this procedure. Thank you Joel for your time.

Comment: I usually just do it like this: for table creation migrations I use `php artisan make:migration create_tablename --create=tablename`, and for table editing migrations I use `php artisan make:migration add_fieldname_to_tablename --table=tablename`. Instead of add I might use edit/delete/drop etc. depending on what I'm trying to accomplish. This way, you're guaranteed not to get duplicates unless you accidentally try to add duplicate fields or tables to the database - in which case it wouldn't work anyway. Hope that helps. :)