# Migrations in Laravel 5.5: Cannot declare class because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

While running a migration in Laravel I got an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class UpdateEnquiriesTable, because the name is already in use in
>   /var/www/project/database/migrations/2018_01_17_160335_update_enquiries_table.php on line 33

Having done a bit of research, I see that each migration file needs a unique class name (I don't remember mention of that before, but that could be me).

According to another question, the recommendation is to [change the name of one of the classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36111496/630530).

But then someone else recommends [deleting the conflicting migrations](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cant-get-migration-to-work).

Which would be the preferred option? Assuming either are valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change one of the class names and then manually update it's entry in the migrations table to preserve your database state. If you delete the conflicting migrations you may run into problems on subsequent migrations and/or rollbacks since the class in question no longer exists.

Comment: So, to be clear, I would change: 1. the file name; 2. it's class name; 3. and the corresponding row in the `migrations` table, correct?

Comment: Yep exactly. This isn't a production database is it?

Comment: This would be on development, but I hit the problem on staging. So if this works, I'd commit the changes, push them to staging, make the same table change, and then run the migrations again.

Comment: Yeah, should work for you. I've had to something similar on a live database.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete this file and retype the migration.
That table is already registered in your migration table so this table will be created even without this file

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following steps:

1. Delete all tables (clear your database)
2. Verify if you really doesn't have duplicated migration classes
3. Verify if all of your migrations has date and time on their filenames
4. Run `composer dump-autoload`
5. Run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Please share more details. How should such a migration work with an existing application? Deleting all tables (and all data within such tables!) does not look like something you should do